# Refactor method that sets two instance variables

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I'm wondering how to refactor this part of code. I need to know how I get a plugin depending on how I found it:

```
  def plugin
    return @plugin unless @plugin.nil?

    @plugin = Plugin.find_by_uid(@plugin_id)
    if @plugin.nil?
      @plugin_found_by = :aid
      @plugin = Plugin.find_by_adid(@plugin_id)
    else
      @plugin_found_by = :uid
    end
    @plugin
  end

  def plugin_found_by
    plugin
    @plugin_found_by
  end
```

Is there a better way to do it ? `plugin` method seems quite repetitive.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. if you're setting instance variables, you don't need to return multiple outputs, you can just later query those variables. If you return multiple outputs, you don't need to set instance variables. Can just use simple locals.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `@plugin` and `@plugin_found_by` are used in other place in my code. This code work I just wanted to know if it's possible to refactor it. Maybe it doesn't need to be refactored ? I'm gonna edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that your `Plugin` class methods are constructors (return a new instance of `Plugin`).

When you create new instances of `Plugin` using the constructors, you should make `@plugin_found_by` an instance variable of the `Plugin` instance, whose value depends on how it was created. You should also have a getter method in `Plugin` class.

```
class Plugin
  attr_reader :plugin_found_by
  def self.find_by_uid(plugin_id)
    @plugin_found_by = :uid
    ...
  end
  def self.find_by_adid(plugin_id)
    @plugin_found_by = :aid
    ...
  end
end
```

Then, your methods in the other class would be:

```
def plugin
  @plugin ||= Plugin.find_by_uid(@plugin_id) || Plugin.find_by_adid(@plugin_id)
end
def plugin_found_by
  plugin.plugin_found_by
end
```

Comment: I think those methods are finders/scopes. So attaching additional logic to them is probably not good. Also it's debatable whether this field (`found_by`) even belongs to plugin. If we were to debate over OOP-purity, this field would belong to a `FoundPlugin`, not `Plugin`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this.

```
def plugin_found_by
  plugin unless @plugin_found_by
  @plugin_found_by
end

def plugin
  find_plugin unless @plugin
  @plugin
end

def get_plugin(type = :uid)
  Plugin.send("find_by_#{type}", @plugin_id)
end

def find_plugin
  config = {:uid => :uid, :aid => :adid}
  @plugin_found_by = config.select { |_, m| @plugin = get_plugin(m); !@plugin.nil? }.keys[0]
end
```

but the better way is to use something like this

```
class Plugin
  attr_reader :found_by

  def self.find_by_uid(id)
    @found_by = :uid
    super(id)
  end

  def self.find_by_adid(id)
    @found_by = :aid
    super(id)
  end
end

def plugin_found_by
  plugin unless @plugin
  @plugin.found_by
end

def plugin
  [:uid, :adid].each { |m|
    if @plugin = Plugin.send("find_by_#{m}", @plugin_id)
      return @plugin
    end
  }
end
```

Comment: thanks for the last one. Love it. Maybe not fan about monkey-patching found_by even with the super.

Comment: @BeniMio I like to help ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another unobtrusive solution that wraps the behaviour you've expressed into its own `PluginFinder` class:

```
class PluginFinder
  FINDER_METHODS = [:uid, :adid]

  def initialize(id)
    @id = id
  end

  def plugin
    @plugin || (find_plugin && @plugin)
  end

  def found_by
    @found_by || (find_plugin && @found_by)
  end

  private

  def find_plugin
    @found_by = FINDER_METHODS.find { |m| find_by(m) }
  end

  def find_by(finder_method)
    @plugin = ::Plugin.send("find_by_#{ finder_method }", @id)
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
finder = PluginFinder.new(1)

plugin = finder.plugin
#=> <Plugin:0x007f7fe5c90dd0>

found_by = finder.found_by
#=> :uid
```

Comment: Your code returns `:adid` not `:aid`, but nice example

Comment: Good catch @LukasBaliak! I'm a little confused as to why OP would want to  return `:aid` when the actual finder method was `:adid`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the code you have shown does not belong to `Plugin` class, and it belongs to another class which is a client of `Plugin` class and it has responsibility to cache an instance of `Plugin` and also keep the information of how it was found, you can rewrite the `plugin` method like below:

```
 def plugin
    @plugin, @plugin_found_by = [Plugin.find_by_uid(@plugin_id), :uid] unless @plugin
    @plugin, @plugin_found_by = [Plugin.find_by_adid(@plugin_id), :aid] unless @plugin
    @plugin
 end
```

Unlike other suggested answers, this solution does not require you to modify the `Plugin` class implementation

Comment: Mine first answer does not require to modify the `Plugin` class ;)